# Is lazy loading B64 images from vuex Store possible?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vue template with 12 img tags

```
<img
    :src="item.logo"
    onerror="this.style.visibility='hidden'"
/>
```

The img tag is inside a loop.

The value of item.logo is for example:

```
"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
```

I do not put here the whole content of the b64, just know that it is a base64 encoded SVG.
The SVGs show correctly.

My problem is that the page rendering is quite long, because the device I use is very slow.
But when I modify the item.logo value by a URI that points to a hosted SVG, the page renders fast without showing at once the svgs, allowing the user to interact with the page while the logos load (lazy load?)

My question:
Is it possible to have a kind of asyncroneous load of these images in the case they are stored in the Vuex store in a b64 format? So the user would still be able to interact with the page while the images get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Vue module for lazyloading images in your applications: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lazyload.

Looks like this is what you need.